# Printing data vertically in columns using paste

Tags: shell, unix

I'm attempting to use paste to list data vertically in two columns.

Pretend I have the below data in a text file

```
Bob:75:Male

Mary:85:Female

Troy:12:Male
```

I extract all the names and store it as a variable:

```
NAMES=$(cat $FILE | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

I also do the same for age

```
AGE=$(cat $FILE | awk -F: '{print $2}')
```

I now would like to paste them together, however paste requires that you use files with text files. For simplicities sake I'd rather not create an extra file, so how do I input the variable into paste to list the data in rows and columns?

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT: Just to clarify I have dumbed down the question, I am doing other things to the data so the solution I'm looking for isn't simply using

```
awk -F: '{print $1 $2}'
```

I need to input to paste using variables from an awk statement.

EDIT #2: To answer the comment it should look like

Bob    75

Mary   85

Tory   12

Comment: Could you post an example of how the final result should look like?

Comment: I've added to the main question as I can't get the formatting right in the comment section @AlbertoZaccagni

Comment: *"I need to input to paste using variables from an awk statement."* -> This smells [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.Your output looks exactly what the `awk` command you say you are not after would produce without stating why this is not what you want. Can you give us a the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve? Also, can you fix the formatting (desired output is no code block; does the input file really contain empty lines? ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` with process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read value from `$file` in 2 arrays
names=()
age=()
while read -r n a; do
   names+=($n)
   age+=($a)
done < <(awk -F: '{print $1, $2}' "$file")

# paste 2 arrays together
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${names[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${age[@]}")
Bob     75
Mary    85
Troy    12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste -d' ' <(echo $NAMES | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo $AGE | tr ' ' '\n')
```